# C# project with ImageList crashes on windows when compiled with mono on linux

Tags: c#, windows, linux, mono, imagelist

I've been successfully compiling a very basic C# visualstudio project (1 button with image from imagelist with 1 item) with mono under linux (xbuild /t:Rebuild on ubuntu lucid) but when I add an imagelist to the project it stills compiles fine and run ok under linux but crashes when run under windows with no specific error message.
any help would be greatly appreaciated.

XBuild Engine Version 2.4.4.0
Mono, Version 2.4.4.0

Comment: Exactly how does it crash? The process just goes away? A message box with an exception message/stack trace? What if you run the program from a command window?

Comment: thanks for answering, yes I'm using winforms for a desktop application. On windows 7 it crashes opening a messagebox with no stack trace saying "a problem is causing the disfunctionning of this application" (translated from french...) and nothing more when run from the command line.

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred so the application is shut down by Windows. You need to use a debugger such as WinDbg to launch this application and then see what is the exception generated. BTW, why do you still use Mono 2.4?

Comment: Mono 2.4 comes as a standard package in ubuntu

Comment: ok so the error is :
    Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***
I'll try to find infos on how to fix this or recompile with a newer version of Mono. 
Thank you very much for the WinDbg tip.